# Создать сокет, доступный для чтения и записи в двух разных контейнерах

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Есть два контейнера, которые поднимаются из docker-compose.yml (привел с сокращениями):

```
version: '3'
services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - sockets:/srv/unix-sockets

  php54-fpm:
    image: php:5.4-fpm
    volumes:
      - sockets:/srv/unix-sockets

volumes:
  sockets:
```

`php-fpm` создает сокет `/srv/unix-sockets/php54-fpm.sock`, который также виден в `nginx`.

Посмотрим права внутри `php-fpm`:

```
ls -la /srv/unix-sockets/php54-fpm.sock
srw-rw---- 1 root root 0 Dec 18 16:59 /srv/unix-sockets/php54-fpm.sock
```

Сокет создался от root, так как этот сервис работает от этого пользователя. Ладно, поменяем владельца:

```
chown www-data:www-data /srv/unix-sockets/php54-fpm.sock
```

Теперь заходим в контейнер `nginx` и проверяем права:

```
ls -la /srv/unix-sockets/php54-fpm.sock
srw-rw----    1 xfs      xfs              0 Dec 18 16:59 /srv/unix-sockets/php54-fpm.sock
```

xfs!!! Ну ладно, это объяснимо:

`nginx`:

```
id xfs
uid=33(xfs) gid=33(xfs) groups=33(xfs),33(xfs)
```

`php-fpm`:

```
id www-data 
uid=33(www-data) gid=33(www-data) groups=33(www-data)
```

Получается, что uid владельца сокета одинаковый, и в разных контейнерах сокет принадлежит разным пользователям.

Но из-за такого поведения воркер `nginx` не видит сокет, и в `error_log` падает это:

```
2019/12/18 16:52:23 [crit] 8#8: *3 connect() to unix:/srv/unix-sockets/php54-fpm.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 88.888.88.88, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/srv/unix-sockets/php54-fpm.sock:", host: "77.777.77.77"
```

Есть такие варианты:

- принудительно в контейнерах менять/создать пользователя www-data с одинаковым uid (смахивает на костыль)
- поменять права на сокет `chmod o+rw` (тоже так себе)
- какой-то другой вариант

Как правильно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Да попросту не используйте unix socket, шлите на 9000 порт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> принудительно в контейнерах менять/создать пользователя www-data с одинаковым uid (смахивает на костыль)

Нет, это не костыль, а необходимое требование для работы (permissions). Проблема заключается, в том, что docker volume монтируется от root. Единственный способ обойти - написать entrypoint script, который запустится после монтирования volumes, а затем запускать сервер.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/unix-sockets
su-exec www-data "$@"
```

> поменять права на сокет chmod o+rw (тоже так себе)

Плохое решение проблемы, если с entrypoint, без не будет работать.

> какой-то другой вариант

Не использовать volume для *.sock. Это будет **более правильный** вариант. Запускать php-fpm по tcp. В nginx.conf прописать в docker domain нотации `proxy_pass http://php54-fpm.$COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME_default:port`, где `php54-fpm` название сервиса, `default` название сети, которая по умолчанию создается.

*Как совет, при возможности не использовать volume, не используйте.*